# How to use service connection string in docker compose inside container within gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab-ci and I have two docker containers, where one shall have access to the other one. But when calling a link inside one container "http://server:3100", then it doesn't work.

I'm inside another docker container. This is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
# Current Version 1.0
image: tiangolo/docker-with-compose:2021-09-18

services:
    - docker:dind

variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

full:
    script:
        - docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from tests
    only:
        - schedules
        - web
develop:
    script:
        - docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from tests
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
          when: always
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    tests:
        build:
            context: ./code
            dockerfile: tests.Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            server:
                condition: service_healthy

    server:
        build:
            context: ./code
            dockerfile: test.server.Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "3100:3100"
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3100"]
            interval: 1m10s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 300
```

In the [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> Within the web container, your connection string to db would look like postgres://db:5432

So I thought, it would be http://server:3100

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Can you paste your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with the question/

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram, I just added the whole .gitlab-cli.yml